# Overwrite Login & Logout controller from spring-security-core to main controller package

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I am using grails 2.1.1 version. I have installed spring-security-core-2.0-RC2 for security. It is installed correctly. but all files and gsp pages are in plugins not in main folders. Is there any way for it to do so and edit if needed ? I have watched some example in googles but no luck. it will be so precious if you help. thanks a lot

Comment: Just copy them into your app and modify them as you need. They will override the plugins versions.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore thanks for your approach. I have paste login and logout controller under controller package and auth.gsp, denied.gsp under views package. But it is giving error as it >> " Message
    No such property: SpringSecurityUtils for class: LoginController"

Comment: should I paste some other files too, if yes then can you suggest me which files please and under which packages ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Paste Login & Logout controller only on the same package as in spring security core plugin to properly overwrite the controllers. (Since plugins files are compiled first)

Another thing you can do is to paste Login & Logout controller in any other package and extend  the plugin's controllers respectively if needed.

Well, you don't need to do that, since plugin provides a script [`s2-quick-start`](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/ref/Scripts/s2-quickstart.html). Running this script will do everything for you.

Thanks,